# Difficulty understanding Silverlight and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, silverlight, expression-blend

I've been reading loads but can't figure out how to apply it to my scenario.
I would like to be able to have a SQL File/server, SQLite or SQL Server and have that on the server for Silverlight to connect to and perform certain queries as more than user will be using the program.

I already have a Project built with Expression Blend, but I don't know how to set up the Web Service for either locating the SQLite file or pointing to the server. Can anyone provide a simply step by step to how I would be able to gain access to the server side with Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, you cannot connect directly to a database through Silverlight; you can only connect back to the web server that served up the Silverlight application and then that server can connect to your database and return the results.

In order to do this, you would use either WCF or RIA in order to connect back to the server and then ultimately to your database.

Comment: I do understand that I need WCF, but I have a standard Silverlight Application, what type of WCF project will I need to create and how can I connect to it?

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal: Well, you would typically create an ASP.NET project (any flavor you like) and then add services (through .svc files).  Then, you would add the service reference in your Silverlight project.  If you are using RIA, then this is already set up for you when you expose your actions on your DomainService.

Comment: You can also connect to other data sources such as SOAP services, JSON, and OData which abstract out the database.